# Modifying Figure numbering

Tags: formatting

How can I modify the numbering of Figures in different sections so they will be labelled 1.1, 1.2 etc in Section 1 and 2.1, 2.2 etc in Section 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a package for that. Add to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
```

You also have the command `counterwithin*{figure}{section}`, which resets the  `figure` counter at a new section, but does not prepend the section counter to `\thefigure`.